# Create a searchable table from one that is organized as a matrix

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am confronted with the following table `sales`:

```
country    2017-Q4    2017-Q3    2017-Q2    ...    1985-Q1
----------------------------------------------------------
Germany      100        200        75                10
Senegal       20         50       130               NULL
Belgium      150         66        22                 5
```

I cannot query this efficiently, for instance "German sales from 2017-Q3".

I would like to reformat this table as follows:

```
country    quarter    sales
---------------------------
Germany    2017-Q4     100
Germany    2017-Q3     200
...
Belgium    1985-Q1       5
```

Can someone help me out on how to accomplish this?

Comment: UNPIVOT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot

Answer (score 1):

I would do this using `cross apply`:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (t.country, '2017-Q4', [2017-Q4]),
             (t.country, '2017-Q3', [2017-Q3]),
             . . .
     ) v(country, quarter, sales);
```

You can also do this using `unpivot` or a `union all` query.  The `apply` syntax implements *lateral joins* which are quite powerful (and have many other uses).  I find that `unpivot` is very bespoke syntax that does one thing (so it is better to learn about lateral joins).

`union all` is less efficient because it reads the table multiple times.